# What do number literals with a suffix, like 0u8, mean in Rust?

Tags: rust, literals

I'm reading through [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html#the-_-placeholder) and have encountered this notation: `0u8`.

```
let some_u8_value = 0u8;
match some_u8_value {
    1 => println!("one"),
    3 => println!("three"),
    5 => println!("five"),
    7 => println!("seven"),
    _ => (),
}
```

After searching the web, I've found lots of examples of this notation being used (`0b01001100u8`, `0x82u8`, `200u8`), but what *exactly* does this notation mean?

Answer (score 42):

### Suffixed Literals

After searching, I've found this explanation in the [same book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#integer-types):

> ... all number literals except the byte literal allow a type suffix, such as `57u8`...

So `0u8` is the number 0 as an unsigned 8-bit integer.

These are referred to as "suffixed literals" and are discussed at length in [Rust By Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/literals.html#literals).

Comment: The documentation on Primitives https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/primitives.html should provide a link Literals  (By Example link above). Also that page.. https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/literals.html#literals - could do with some rework - The example detracts. The lines at the top convey enough. Makes it easier to scan. The whole size in bytes/mem stuff is a whole different concept that muddies waters. asserts would make more sense it is really necessary to deviate from the concept.

Comment: I saw this line in the docs and immediately wondered "what's the difference between a 'byte literal' and a 'u8', an unsigned 8-bit int.